# Casting Operator on a null string in Specman

Tags: specman

I am developing some RTL checkers in Specman E and using type conversion to process a command line argument.

The code is as follows,

```
if(get_symbol("SWITCH").as_a(uint) > 10) {

  do something;

};
```

The command line has an option SWITCH=10. The problem is the test fails if there is no switch with the error.

```
*** Error: Looking for a number but found 'an empty string'
```

How can I avoid this error? Is there is way to give some default value to the casting operator so that whenever it processes null it returns a zero instead? Ofcourse I can first check whether the string is null and only then proceed. But I want to avoid that extra line and see if I can play around with `as_a`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how casting from string to number works - if it's not a number, you get an error.
You could wrap it in a `try` block to catch the error, but if you know for sure that the only other possibility is an empty string (and not any other non-number string), the best solution is simply to check whether the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't work around this problem without having the extra line.

The `.as_a()` is function of the `string` object, but `get_symbol()` will return a `null` string if `SWITCH` is not defined in the command line.